# Excel crashes while compiling in a line contains label and DoEvents keyword

Tags: excel, vba

I have below 3 lines which are part of a procedure which makes the Excel crash. I have given them as four procedures with different names to be clear.

**Lines which make the Excel crash:**

```
Sub CrashVersion1()
163:                    Do
164:                    Loop Until Timer - st >= 0.5
165:                    DoEvents
End Sub

Sub CrashVersion2()
163:                    Do
164:                    DoEvents
165:                    Loop Until Timer - st >= 0.5

End Sub
```

**Lines which don't create problem:**

```
Sub FineVersion()
163:                    Do
164:                    Loop Until Timer - st >= 0.5
'DoEvents without a Label
                    DoEvents
End Sub

Sub FineVersion2()
163:                    Do
164:                    Loop Until Timer - st >= 0.5
Application.StatusBar = "PL"
166:                    DoEvents
End Sub
```

1. The macro runs if `DoEvents` is above `Do` or after (but not immediately after) `Do` and `Loop` or when there is no label for it.
2. The Excel crashes if `DoEvents` is in between `Do` and `Loop` or immediately after `Do` and `Loop` ONLY when there is a label.

I can put `DoEvents` without a label but just curious to know what is happening and a solution or workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Timer function returns the number of seconds since midnight as a `Single` datatype.

[Microsoft documentation for the Timer function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function)

The st variable is never initialised

`FineVersion2()` runs OK on my computer.

`FineVersion1()` runs OK on my computer.

`CrashVersion2()` runs OK on my computer.

`CrashVersion1()` appears to loop continuously on my computer. (blue circle) Excel has not crashed and can be closed via the red X in the top right hand corner.

The following code runs OK on my computer.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CrashVersionNoColons()
Dim st As Single
163                    Do
164                    Loop Until Timer - st >= 0.5
165                    DoEvents
End Sub
```

There are no colons and this runs OK

As I see it there are two ways the compiler could see the code

`163:  Do`

pseudo code

line number 163 / blank statement / colon statement divider / valid `Do` statement

=> should run OK but it does not

or

pseudo code

illegal label 163: (does not start with a letter) / ignore the `Do` statement

=> should produce an error message but it does not

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2311 Build 16.0.17029.20028) 64-bit

But read this Microsoft documentation [Label statements in Visual BASIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-label-statements) this gives an example with the 163: syntax as a valid label.

From the [Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#line-label)

*Used to identify a single line of code, a line label can be any combination of characters that starts with a letter and ends with a colon (:). Line labels are not case sensitive and must begin in the first column.*

I realise this is an inconclusive answer but it may help in understanding what is happeniing and what the workaround could be.

Comment: Black cat's answer is simple but user10186832's answer is elaborative and removing colon for `DoEvents` statement line made the macro run.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the label using in the code.

If you use line numbers for labelling then don't add `:` colon to the end, then Excel will not crashes.

Use only `:` colon when line labels are used. (Start with a letter and end with a colon)